# Textbox in new line if reach some count

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, newline

I have div, based on drop-down text-box will add to div. But if reach some count text-box will come next line. currently text-box append one by one. please find my code in below.

```
    $("#HowmanyClone_Id").change(function () {

            var html = '';
            var cloneCount = $(this).find(":selected").text();
            for (var i = 1; i <= cloneCount; i++) {
                    html += '<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">' + i + '. Serial Number: <input type="text" name="Sr_NoValues" class="form-control "> </div>';
                }                    
                html += '<br/>' + '<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;"> Comments: <input type="text" name="Sr_NoValues" class="form-control "> </div>';
                $("#AddingtoDiv").empty().append(html);
        });
```

below my HTML Code

```
    <div id="Div_Quick_Clone" style="display: none;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            No of Clones :</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%=Html.DropDownList("HowmanyClone_Id", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem{ Text="Select To Clone", Value = "Select" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="1", Value = "1" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2", Value = "2" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="3", Value = "3" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="4", Value = "4" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="5", Value = "5" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="6", Value = "6" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="7", Value = "7" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="8", Value = "8" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="9", Value = "9" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="10", Value = "10" },                                                        
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="11", Value = "11" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="12", Value = "12" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="13", Value = "13" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="14", Value = "14" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="15", Value = "15" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="16", Value = "16" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="17", Value = "17" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="18", Value = "18" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="19", Value = "19" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="20", Value = "20" },                                                        
                        }, new { id = "HowmanyClone_Id" })%>
        </div>
        <div id="AddingtoDiv"></div>
    </div>
```

Please check my HMTL code in above

Comment: please share relevant html code with the question above

Comment: Thanks for your reply my textbox are in html. that html wiill append to to div(#AddingtoDiv). adding textbox to down (one by one). i need if more then 10 textbox 11th textbox will come next line i mean beside first textbox.

Comment: the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters) in `parseInt` can be between 2 and 36 so `parseInt(cloneCount, 40)` is definitely wrong.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have updated code workin fine i need my textbox will come in next line i.e( /n ). if more then 10

Comment: @ Gabriele Petrioli, Hi here problem is add textbox to new line in div. not parseInt